# How do I insert a row every three cells in a large spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Hoping you can help an basic excel user please!

I have a file of around 2000 rows and I need to add a line/break after every third one. Is there a simple way of doing this please?

Your help and advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know how to use VBA?

Comment: I am afraid not Matthew, if can be explained then I  pick things up quickly!

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say it can be easily explained but there are many free tutorials for beginners out there. Here is one http://www.excelvbatutor.com/vba_book/vbabook_ed2.pdf  Take a look at that and I'll post an answer that will show you how to do it in VBA so if you want to give it a try you can start there.

Comment: I will get studying, that is so helpful, thank you! I've downloaded the doc but may be a while!

Comment: You can do just about anything with VBA.  The SO community can help you learn also.  If you try some code and get errors or get stuck. Post your code here with a description of the error or question. Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick way without VBA

1. In a empty column add this formula, `=IF(MOD(ROW(),3)=0,NA(),"")` and copy down
2. Press F5, `Goto` .... `Special`, `Formulas` `Errors` (selects every third row)
3. Insert Rows

*step 2 shown below*

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much. Added an additional row at the top and worked a treat! You guys really are the best, thank you everyone for your time and expertise, you are all brilliant!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to try some VBA here is a button click event that will do the insert on every third row. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

    'Set the worksheet object to the sheet by name
    Set ws = Application.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'Set the row to start looping(inserting) rows at
    lRow = 4

    'Find the last row with a value in column A
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'Account for the amount of rows that will be inserted.
    lastRow = lastRow + (lastRow * 0.33)

    'Loop through the worksheet from the start row to the last row
    Do While lRow <= lastRow

        'Insert a row
        ws.Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Insert

    'Increment the row to insert at on the next pass of the loop
    lRow = lRow + 4
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: @Jeeped.  It does compensate for the inserted row by incrementing by four when he only wants a new row every three rows. So it is really skipping the newly inserted row and the next three rows.

Comment: @Jeeped I see what you mean. Good point. I used a small sample but with thousands of rows, it will insert hundreds rows, the found last row does not account for those lines.  I have made the change.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

a non vba way is create a new column and insert numbering

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
......
```

then for empty row, number as 3,6,9,.... (let say u have 2k records, duplicate it 2k)
then sort by the number column, then remove the column

[image][image]

Comment: Good method. I had been thinking about populating a 'helper' column with a variant array and sorting the same way. This should be faster than individually inserting ~670 rows or bulk inserting ~670 discontiguous rows.

Answer (score 0):

If your content is the same, or repeating, for each row, you could open the file in any basic text editor and do the following:

1. Highlight and copy the first three rows (including the third line break).
2. Using find-and-replace (Opt-Cmd-F in TextEdit on Macs), copy that content into the 'find' field as well as the 'replace' field.
3. Add a line break at the end of the content you pasted in the 'replace' field.
4. Execute the find-and-replace action.

This should turn something like this:

```
item
item
item
item
item
item
item
```

...into this:

```
item
item
item

item
item
item

item
```

...and so on.

This definitely isn't the most elegant solution, but is one of the quickest/simplest I've seen without resorting to a text parsing script in bash, etc.

Comment: Thanks so much Gravity Black but unfortunately each cell has individual data in

Comment: Ah, okay. Could you perhaps post a sample of the content so that we could give you a better idea of what your options are?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data starts in A1, in B1 and copied down to suit (i.e. past the end of the cells populated in ColumnA):

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),4)=0,"",OFFSET(A$1,3*INT((ROW()-1)/4)+MOD(ROW(),4)-1,))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a VBA equivalent to the solution proposed by [Eric K.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5623502/eric-k) above. The orientation assumes column header labels in row 1 that should be left alone.

```
Sub insBlankFourthRow()
    Debug.Print Timer
    With Worksheets("Sheet3")
        .Columns(1).Insert
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion  '<~~ original CurrentRegion
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 0)
                .Cells(1, 1) = 1
                .Cells.DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Step:=1
            End With
            With .Resize(Int(.Rows.Count / 3) + 1, 1).Offset(.Rows.Count, 0)
                .Cells(1, 1) = 3.5
                .Cells.DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Step:=3
            End With
        End With
        '
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion  '<~~ new expanded CurrentRegion
            .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
        End With
        .Columns(1).Delete
    End With
    Debug.Print Timer
End Sub
```

tbh, ~2000 rows of data isn't that much to be worried about but 10× or 100× that amount of data will start to lag significantly when inserting rows individually or in a bulk non-contiguous orientation. A 'helper' column populated with a [Range.DataSeries method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839262.aspx) (fastest way I know of populating a sequence) can be readily discarded once its purpose has been fulfilled.

[image: insert_blank_fourth_row]

Running the above against 2500 rows of random data typical of the image took ⁸⁄₁₀₀ of a second. That time might be moderately improved with disabling the [Application.ScreenUpdating property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193498.aspx) and similar overhead.